# Issues with System.Globalization.HebrewCalendar class?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, calendar, globalization

I have the following code, a simple example on which I want to expand to compute the Yartzeit dates (death anniversaries). 
The code adds 1 month to the Jewish date 5771/1/1. It gives me an exception and I can't figure out why (I have very little knowledge of Jewish dates):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Threading 

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim hc As New HebrewCalendar()
        Dim jewishCulture As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("he-IL")
        jewishCulture.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = hc
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = jewishCulture
        Dim startDate = new DateTime(5771,1,1)
        Console.WriteLine(startDate.ToString())
        startDate = hc.AddMonths(startDate, 1)      
        Console.WriteLine(startDate.ToString())
    End Sub
End Module
```

Here is the result (from .NET Fiddle, I have the same result locally):

```
1/1/5771 12:00:00 AM
Run-time exception (line -1): Value to add was out of range.
Parameter name: months

Stack Trace:

[System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Value to add was out of range.
Parameter name: months]
```

According to the documentation on the HebrewCalendar.AddMonths Method ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.hebrewcalendar.addmonths(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.hebrewcalendar.addmonths%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), the ArgumentOutOfRangeException should be thrown if "months is less than -120,000 or greater than 120,000.". This is obviously not the case here, I add 1 month to month #1. 
Are there known issues with the .NET HebrewCalendar class ? Or something else I am missing?

Thank you,

PS: I'm using the HebrewCalendar.AddMonths rather than the DateTime.AddMonths method because of the following remark on HebrewCalendar.AddMonths: "The day part of the resulting DateTime is affected if the resulting day is not a valid day in the resulting month of the resulting year. It is changed to the last valid day in the resulting month of the resulting year.".

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

- You are assigning the culture to the `CurrentUICulture`.  That will have no effect on `DateTime`.  The UI culture determines which localization resource file to use if you have localized resx files.  You should set the `CurrentCulture` instead, which is used in number and date formatting.

  ```
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = jewishCulture
  ```
- If you're not using the Gregorian calendar when you construct a `DateTime` from individual year, month, day parts, you *must* pass the calendar as a parameter. [See the remarks in the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x.aspx).

  ```
  Dim startDate = new DateTime(5771,1,1, hc)
  ```

  Keep in mind that the `DateTime` object itself is just a wrapper around the number of ticks passed since 0001/01/01 in the Gregorian calendar.  It *always* uses the Gregorian calendar in its properties and methods.  (If you look at `startDate.Year`, it will be 2010, not 5771.)

  To add "1 Hebrew month" - you *must* call `HebrewCalendar.AddMonths` rather than `DateTime.AddMonths`.  You have this right, but it's not just for the reason you described.

Also, you may be interested in Jon Skeet's latest work in [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) 1.3 which adds experimental support for the Hebrew calendar.  Please read under ["Hebrew" in the user guide](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/calendars.html), and read [the comments in the 1.3 release notes](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2014/06/noda-time-1.3.0.html).  In general, I trust Jon's interpretation of the Hebrew calendar better than I trust the .Net Framework's `HebrewCalendar` class.  (See [this discussion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/39053).)